# Create a row in an airtable base from static html form

Tags: javascript, html, airtable

I have a static landing page, and would like to create a simple waitlist in airtable using only plain html/javascript.

I created a simple form on my landing page, that only accepts an e-mail. After pressing "submit" button, I would like to post this e-mail to my airtable base. I guess it can be done by a simple POST request.

Does anyone have an example for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this, but doing so would require you to expose your Airtable API key in the public facing HTML page which **is not recommended**.  Anyone could find that key in your page and then use it.

You can make a `POST` request to create a new record in a base.  To make it successfully, you need:

1. Your API key
2. Base ID
3. Table ID for the specific table you want records to be created in

You can see https://airtable.com/api for more details.  The [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) code would looks something like:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Authorization", `Bearer ${YOUR_API_KEY}`);
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

var data = {
  fields: {
    Email: `${email_in_form_submission}`
  }
}
var raw = JSON.stringify(data);

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch(`https://api.airtable.com/v0/${YOUR_BASE_ID}/${YOUR_TABLE_ID}`, requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

#### Airtable Forms

Would also recommend looking at Airtable's native [Form Views](https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/206058268-Guide-to-forms) which allow you to create a public facing form that people can submit and have the data go directly into your base.  The forms can also be [embedded as iframes](https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/206058268-Guide-to-forms#share) if you want to insert the form on a page you own and control.